# New to python and first time trying to publish Stored procedure

Tags: python, sql, stored-procedures, pyodbc

Getting the following error when trying to access the webpage.

Could not open page @ /ProdRep

Reason: 'long' object has no attribute 'replace'

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=SQL01;DATABASE=DB101;UID=sa;PWD=Password')
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = """EXEC [DB101].[dbo].[_GetStockMovement]
        @FromDate = '2019-01-05',
        @ToDate = '2019-01-06' """

cursor.execute(sql)
data = cursor.fetchall()

for row in data :
    print (row[1])
    print (data)
    data
```

When running the stored procedure in sms it works fine.  It's my first crack at publishing a stored procedure.

Comment: Using the `@` symbol usually indicates a declared variable. Since you are passing these into the sproc, you aren't declaring them, but assigning them. Remove the `@` in your call. Inside the sproc itself, the variable will be labeled as `@FromDate` and you'll use it like `WHERE FromDate = @FromDate`

Comment: Also, is this the correct way to call a stored procedure in `pyodbc`?  https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Calling-Stored-Procedures